# Context aware menu in a batch files

Tags: batch-file, command-line, cmd

Script starts up and identifies via text file name in folder 'C:\ProgramData\WorkingDir', the current database the  software is going to connect to \has been using. There is a menu choice to continue and just connect as it has been, Or choose a different database. A different database can be chosen simply by backing up the current workingdir contents to its own folder (for restring later during switching) and over writing the workingdir with folders from the other choices.

all sub folder and files named identical - contents differ to enable different database access.

C:\ProgramData\WorkingDir\Azure.txt

C:\Folder\Azure\Azure.txt

c:\Folder\Oracle\Oracle.txt

c:\Folder\SQL\SQL.txt

So I have the script working fine using robocopy to mir everything to the right place.

Only problem is the menu switching choice contains the current database in use an option to swtich to which looks stupid. I want to be able to have the current database in use "absent" from the choices. Here is what it looks like

```
Your current database is Azure 
choose 1 to continue 
choose 2 to choose a different database 

extra menu 
Press 1 for Azure 
Press 2 for Oracle 
Press 3 for SQL 

what it needs to do is 'not' give a choice of the current database as it's pointless 

so..(ideally)

Your current database is Azure 
choose 1 to continue 
choose 2 to choose a different database 

extra menu
Press 1 for Oracle
Press 2 for SQL

or 

Your current database is SQL 
choose 1 to continue 
choose 2 to choose a different database 

extra menu
Press 1 for Oracle
Press 2 for Azure

or 


Your current database is ORACLE
choose 1 to continue 
choose 2 to choose a different database 

extra menu
Press 1 for SQL
Press 2 for Azure

NOT 

Your current database is ORACLE
choose 1 to continue 
choose 2 to choose a different database 

Press 1 for SQL
Press 2 for Azure
Press 3 for Oracle
```

All the folder copying and input commands are fine its just this menu issue. 
I tried to ask this before but over complicated it and some kind folks got close with an 'array'.

Comment: There is only one `.txt` file in `C:\ProgramData\WorkingDir\`?

Comment: yeah so i know and the script knows what database is in the config files in that folder I add that text files manually. So if I want to switch between 3 or even 4, i know which is which and can copy into working dir through the menu choices. Hope that makes sense. Because the contents of working dir are identical few folders and a cfg file. The text allows to differentiate.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy using the `CHOICE` command. Maybe I do not understand part of your requirement. I did not go through the exercise of copying files since you said you had that working.

As for not having the current database appear as a possible selection, why not let it appear? If they choose it, the code will recognize the situation and not copy it off.

```
@ECHO OFF
SET "WORKDIR=C:\ProgramData\WorkingDir"

:MenuHead
SET "CURDB=unknown"
IF EXIST "%WOKDIR%\Azure.txt" (SET "CURDB=Azure")
IF EXIST "%WORKDIR%\Oracle.txt" (SET "CURDB=Oracle")
IF EXIST "%WORKDIR%\SQL.txt" (SET "CURDB=SQL Server")
ECHO Your current database is %CURDB%

CHOICE /C AOSX /M "Choose A=Azure O=Oracle S=SQL Server X=Exit menu"
IF ERRORLEVEL 4 GOTO OutaHere
IF ERRORLEVEL 3 GOTO DoSQLServer
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO DoOracle
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO DoAzure

ECHO NB: Unknown selection %ERRORLEVEL%
GOTO MenuHead

:DoSQLServer
IF NOT EXIST "%WORKDIR%\SQL.txt" (
    CALL:BackupCurrent
    ECHO copy SQL Server in
)
GOTO MenuHead

:DoOracle
IF NOT EXIST "%WORKDIR%\Oracle.txt" (
    CALL:BackupCurrent
    ECHO copy Oracle in
)
GOTO MenuHead

:DoAzure
IF NOT EXIST "%WORKDIR%\Azure.txt" (
    CALL:BackupCurrent
    ECHO copy Azure in
)
GOTO MenuHead

:OutaHere
EXIT /B 0

REM ==================

:BackupCurrent

IF EXIST "%WORKDIR%\Azure.txt" (
    echo save off Azure
)
IF EXIST "%WORKDIR%\Oracle.txt" (
    ECHO save off Azure
)
IF EXIST "%WORKDIR%\Azure.txt" (
    ECHO save off SQL Server
)
GOTO :EOF
```

Comment: FYI this post has been really helpful, not a fan of choice so have gone back to set /p but most of it the same, having the exisitng db as a choice has saved a lot of trouble. Will post shortly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This finds the databases (folders) on it's own, so we don't have to hardcode them.
We don't need a subroutine for every single database.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set "progdata=C:\ProgramData\Company\WorkingDir"
set "spdir=C:\ProgramData\Company"
REM get current database:
for %%a in (*.txt) do set current=%%~na
REM get possible databases [folders]:
set x=0
set "c="
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('dir /b /ad "%progdata%\*.txt"') do (
  set /a x+=1
  set "m[!x!]=%%a"
  set "c=!c!!x!"
)
REM print menu:
for /l %%a in (1,1,%x%) do (
  echo %%a - !m[%%a]!|find /v /i "%current%"
)
REM ask for new selection:
choice /n /c %c% /m "Select new database: "
set new=!m[%errorlevel%]!
if %new%==%current% (
  echo same - no switching 
  goto :eof
)
REM do the moving:
robocopy "%progdata%" "%spdir%\%current%" /MIR >nul 2>&1 & robocopy "%spdir%\%new%" "%progdata%" /MIR >nul 2>&1
start "" "C:\Temp\Shortcut.lnk" & goto :eof
```

`|find /v /i "%current%"` suppresses the output of the current database.

Note: there shouldn't be more than 9 databases (folders) because we use numbers and `choice` can only handle sinlge "key" (if there are / may be more than 9, switch back to `set /p`).

(I used some info from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45884733/2152082))